# Lisp format directive that interprets nil argument to empty string instead of "NIL"

Tags: lisp, format, common-lisp

I know I can process the argument before passing it, I just wonder if there is a directive for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [CL Format recipe: Dealing with nil as a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101505/cl-format-recipe-dealing-with-nil-as-a-value)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~@[~A~]" "foo")
"foo"
CL-USER> (format nil "~@[~A~]" nil)
""
```