# CL Format recipe: Dealing with nil as a value

Tags: format, common-lisp

I've been looking through formatting recipes , and I can't quite find what I'm looking for...

`(format nil CONTROL-STRING day name num-apples)`

Suppose I don't want to change the arguments in the above form, just `CONTROL-STRING`.

`day` and `num-apples` will always be non-nil, but `name` might be nil.

When `name` is nil, I want the output to look like

`"Today is Monday. Hello, you have 3 apples."`

but when `name` is defined, I want it to look like

`"Today is Monday. Hello Adam, you have 3 apples."`

So the control string needs to look at `name`, use it in the non-nil case, not use it in the nil case, but consume it in both cases.

Maybe it can be accomplished by consuming nil and printing it as `""`? If so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: My original search-fu wasn't good enough. I think this has my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729032/lisp-format-directive-that-interprets-nil-argument-to-empty-string-instead-of-n?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question you linked to, [Lisp format directive that interprets nil argument to empty string instead of "NIL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729032/lisp-format-directive-that-interprets-nil-argument-to-empty-string-instead-of-n?rq=1), does include an answer that shows how you can do this, but doesn't cite any of the documentation.  Since you're generating English text, there are also a few other options that you might want to consider as well.

First, with **~@[consequent~]**, you can process the **consequent** format directive just in the case that the argument is non-nil, and the argument to **~@[** isn't consumed, so it's still available. In general, 
[22.3.7.2 Tilde Left-Bracket: Conditional Expression](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cgb.htm) describes lots of options, but about **~@[** it says:

> ~@[consequent~] tests the argument. If it is true, then the argument
>   is not used up by the ~[ command but remains as the next one to be
>   processed, and the one clause consequent is processed. If the arg is
>   false, then the argument is used up, and the clause is not processed.
>   The clause therefore should normally use exactly one argument, and may
>   expect it to be non-nil.

You can use this as follows:

```
(defun test (day name n-apples)
  (format nil "Today is ~a. Hello~@[ ~a~], you have ~a apples."
          day name n-apples))
```

```
CL-USER> (test 'monday 'adam 2)
"Today is MONDAY. Hello ADAM, you have 2 apples."
CL-USER> (test 'tuesday nil 42)
"Today is TUESDAY. Hello, you have 42 apples."
```

To make this even more robust, you should consider using [~p for pluralization](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_chc.htm), so that you get "1 apple" and "3 apple**s**".

```
(defun test (day name n-apples)
  (format nil "Today is ~a. Hello~@[ ~a~], you have ~a apple~:P."
          day name n-apples))
```

```
CL-USER> (test 'monday 'john 2)
"Today is MONDAY. Hello JOHN, you have 2 apples."
CL-USER> (test 'tuesday 'john 1)
"Today is TUESDAY. Hello JOHN, you have 1 apple."
CL-USER> (test 'wednesday nil 0)
"Today is WEDNESDAY. Hello, you have 0 apples."
```

Finally, since you're generating text, you might appreciate some case normalization (e.g., print proper nouns with initial capitals), and writing the numbers in text:

```
(defun test (day name n-apples)
  (format nil "Today is ~:(~a~). Hello~@[ ~:(~a~)~], you have ~r apple~:P."
          day name n-apples))
```

```
CL-USER> (list
          (test 'monday 'adam 4)
          (test 'tuesday 'john 1)
          (test 'wednesday 'mary\ sue 42)
          (test 'thursday 'jim-bob 0))
("Today is Monday. Hello Adam, you have four apples."
 "Today is Tuesday. Hello John, you have one apple."
 "Today is Wednesday. Hello Mary Sue, you have forty-two apples."
 "Today is Thursday. Hello Jim-Bob, you have zero apples.")
```